# How I can connect wp container with ajenti container?

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have an VPS with some services in it all based on Docker. Etherpad, Rocketchat, Nextcloud and some Wordpress sites.

We need that users could use graphical file manager to administer their Wordpress instances. Ideally I would like that all those apps could be integrated on a panel.

I come up with Ajenti panel https://github.com/niiknow/ajenti-udock, I'm planning to use this image based on Ubuntu but I'll prefer to use Debian based.

I know I can launch Worpress sites within Ajenti, but I prefer to have WP on different containers.

Witch is the way to attach the Wordpress instances I have on Ajenti?
or is there a better solution to achieve what I need?

I want to avoid sftp and ssh because as I understood could be a security hole for Docker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, you don't need to install sshd inside your docker image. You can access to runnign container with docker command *exec* like this:

    $ docker exec -it <containerId|containerName> bash

I do  not know Ajenti, but if you need to launch new container from Ajenti GUI i think you need to find or develop some plugin/module

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Actually to go inside my containers I'm already using $ docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash. I know is not a good practice to use ssh with Docker. What I actually need more is that Ajenti panel recognizes my Wp containers.